# Annoying guy on Gmail, how do I ignore him?

Tags: gmail

I have this annoying guy that post on a email list I'm on. Is there some easy way to ignore the fellow in Gmail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put in a filter that either automatically deletes the emails from him (pretty drastic) or better yet just label & automatically archive them.  The advantage of the second way is that you can still easily access the emails should you wish, but they do not appear in your inbox.
Taking the person's name as "Stalker", the filter should look something like:

[image]

You can create the label at the same time as you create the filter.

Comment: dumb question... since Gmail does the conversation view for threads on mailing lists, how does labeling the entire conversation as "stalker" help here? Deleting *just* the email from "stalker-dude" removes the whole conversation, if I am not mistaken

Comment: No, I don't think it does. It just deletes that single email, and the rest of the conversation remains unharmed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't think deleting his email is drastic. I really want to kill him, but that would be drastic :)

Comment: killing is illegal